# Having problems with getting a animated heatmap with Seaborn

Tags: animation, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to create a animated heatmap.
All the example I can find online works for random array generator and works.
When I trying to do the same with a per-populated array, it does not work, I am doing something wrong, please help.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

%matplotlib notebook
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [5, 5]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True


mydata=np.zeros((20,5,5))
mydata.shape
for i in range(20):
    mydata[i]=i/2
    

fig = plt.figure()

def init():
    sns.heatmap(mydata[1], vmax=.8, cbar=False)

def animate(i):
    sns.heatmap(mydata[i], vmax=.8, cbar=False,square=True)


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=10, repeat=False)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean be "does not work"?  A crash? An error message? A black screen? .... ?  `vmax=.8` could give an error when all the values are larger than `.8`. For an animation you need a fixed `vmin` and `vmax`.

Comment: A black screen! thank you, you ended my two days of frustration! I did not notice vmax!

Comment: You probably need to set both `vmin` and `vmax`. Any may use `mydata[0]` and `square=True` inside `init()`.  If your problem is solved now, maybe you could close the question?